# How do I let Netbeans automatically compile Sass on save?

Tags: sass, netbeans, netbeans-8

I am working with SASS in Netbeans 8. Now I have a project structure as:

```
 ProjectMap
  |
  |-- index.php 
  |    
  |-- css
  |    |-- style.css
  |
  |-- _dev
        |-- sass
              |-- style.scss
              |-- components
                    |-- header.scss
                    |-- footer.scss
```

*Settings:*

Input: `/_dev/sass`

Output: `/css`

Compiler options: `-I ${web.root}/_dev/scss --load-path ${web.root}/_dev/scss  --style compressed`

Style.scss does @import header and footer. When I save the style.scss, Netbeans runs the Sass compiler and generates. Only if I save header.scss or footer.scss it does not trigger the Sass compiler. How to let Netbeans automatically compile on save?

- Netbeans 8 (Build 201403101706) on MacOS
- Sass 3.3.14
- Compass 0.12.7 (Alnilam)

Comment: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCompileOnSave

Comment: Thanks for the link. Read the page, but could not find a solution or the problem on it for me.

Answer (score 0):

did you check the checkbox "Compile Sass Files on Save"?
In my case, I don't use any compiler options and it's working fine. 
It compiles all the sub-folder files (in /styles/scss/) when I save them. 
[image: netbeans project properties window]
(To get this window, right click on the project in project pannel > properties, but I think you already have figured it out.)